SpdLog, RuntimeError: async log: thread pool doesn't exist anymore
Here is my code, if I enabled async_mode=True, I will get
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/root/tradebot-pro/example/test_log.py", line 28, in <module>
    logger1.info("Kukucs-info")
RuntimeError: async log: thread pool doesn't exist anymore

import spdlog
import time
import os



daily_sink = spdlog.daily_file_sink_mt(filename="daily.log", rotation_hour=0, rotation_minute=0)
daily_sink.set_level(spdlog.LogLevel.INFO)

stdout_sink = spdlog.stdout_color_sink_mt()
stdout_sink.set_level(spdlog.LogLevel.DEBUG)


sinks = [
    stdout_sink,
    daily_sink,
]


logger1 = spdlog.SinkLogger("Hello", sinks, async_mode=True)
logger1.set_level(spdlog.LogLevel.DEBUG)    
logger1.flush_on(spdlog.LogLevel.DEBUG)

logger2 = spdlog.SinkLogger("Good-bye", sinks, async_mode=True)
logger2.set_level(spdlog.LogLevel.DEBUG)
logger2.flush_on(spdlog.LogLevel.DEBUG)

logger1.info("Kukucs-info")
logger2.error("Kukucs-error")
logger1.debug("Kukucs-debug")
logger2.warn("Kukucs-warn")
logger1.info("Alma-info")


logger1.info("Kukucs-info")
logger2.error("Kukucs-error")
logger1.debug("Kukucs-debug")
logger2.warn("Kukucs-warn")
logger1.info("Alma-info")

I tried disable the asyncmode, it worked, but I still want async mode.
